# Java Records StackOverflow RuntimeException

Tags: java, stack-overflow, tostring, java-14, java-record

I am learning Java Records, preview feature and I am getting a StackOverflow exception when I run the below piece of code .

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;
    public class Example {
        public record Course(String name, Student topper) { }
        public record Student(String name, List<Course> enrolled) {}

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Student john = new Student("John", new ArrayList<>());
            john.enrolled().add(new Course("Enrolled for Math", john));
            john.enrolled().add(new Course("Enrolled for History", john));
            System.out.println(john);
        }
    }


Below is the exception trace :


 java --enable-preview Example
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at Example$Course.toString(Example.java:6)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:3388)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:167)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:457)
```

From the exception I realize that it has to do with toString() and when I have override toString() in the records as below code I don't see the Exception .

```
// code with implementation of toString()
public class Example {

    public record Course(String name, Student topper) {
    public String toString()
        {
            return name;
        }
   }
   public record Student(String name, List<Course> enrolled) {
   public String toString()
        {
             return this.name+" : "+enrolled.stream().map(s->s.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
        }
   }
   public static void main(String... args) {
       Student john = new Student("John", new ArrayList<>());
       john.enrolled().add(new Course("Enrolled for Math", john));
       john.enrolled().add(new Course("Enrolled for History", john));
       System.out.println(john);
   }
}
```

This code prints John : Enrolled for Math,Enrolled for History . Can someone please explain why if I don't override  toString() I get StackOverflow? Also I see StackOverflow when I print `john.hashCode()`

Comment: Same deal with `hashCode()` and `equals()`.

Comment: Note that it is easy to construct the same problem without records.  `var x = new ArrayList(); var y = new ArrayList(); x.add(y); y.add(x)`, and then call `toString()` on either `x` or `y`.  Almost no "nice" `toString()` method is immune from SOE in the presence of cycles.

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with `Record#toString` in particular. Take a closer look at your declaration:

```
public record Course(String name, Student topper) {}
public record Student(String name, List<Course> enrolled) {}
```

`Course#toString` needs `Student#toString` and `Student#toString` needs `Course#toString`. So if you try to print `Student` then all enrolled `Course` will be printed along. Those `Course`s needs `Student` so they will print `Student` inside. This loop will continue till you get `StackOverflow` exception.

To avoid this kind of scenario, you should rearrange your code so they don't depend on each other. You can create an id per instance. An example would be:

```
public record Course(String name, String studentId) {}
public record Student(String name, String studentId, List<Course> courses) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

As others pointed out, the issue is that you have a circular reference in your record.

You are able to create such a circular reference because Records are only shallowly immutable.
In your case, `enrolled` is a `List<Course>`, that you initialize with an empty `ArrayList<>`.

To avoid that, you should make a defensive copy when creating the record:

```
public record Student(String name, List<Course> enrolled) {
    public Student {
        enrolled = List.copyOf(enrolled);
    }
}
```

You then have to supply a list of the courses when you create a Student:

```
List<Course> courses = List.of(
        new Course("Enrolled for Math", null),
        new Course("Enrolled for History", null)
);
Student john = new Student("John", courses);
```

This makes it impossible to have a circular reference.
But it looks like your model requires those circular references. So you might need to change the model.

Comment: Thanks , I liked this idea.

Comment: @DebapriyaBiswas This is essentially the same as `john.enrolled().add(new Course("Enrolled for Math", null));`. So if you didn't even make a copy your code will work fine with `john.enrolled().add(new Course("Enrolled for Math", null));`. Not really sure what you like about this solution.

Comment: @DebapriyaBiswas Try and compile this code: https://www.pastiebin.com/5ed7242b1283a It is effectively same as this answer.

Comment: No, my answer changes the design - by enforcing immutability.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I agree with you . I liked John's idea but doesn't solve the problem at hand .I am looking for a good design pattern practice to avoid having circular reference in future. Do you suggest  override hashCode(),toString(), equals() for such cases .

Comment: If you don't want to have circular references, make everything immutable.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're trying to print a list of courses that the student is enrolled in, and each of those courses has that same student listed as enrolled. So you have a circular reference. Course -> Student -> Course -> Student etc.

When you overrode Course toString(), you only printed the name so this was no longer an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your structure is the following `Student`-> `List<Course>` and `Course`-> `Student` which builds a circular chain and the `toString` method runs in loop.

From the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Record.html) for records:

> Object.toString() methods are derived from all of the component
>   fields.

When you do `System.out.println(john)` `toString` is called for the `Student` john then it is delegated to all the enrolled `Course` instances for which `toString` is called and as a `Course` instance has a reference to a `Student` instance again...the whole chain runs until a `StackOverflowException` is thrown.